# Predictive splitting of XML file by byte size

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML messages `xmlStr` that must be split into smaller XML messages, that are less or equal to `maxSizeBytes`. This is done by taking a root of document and it first child as a base for smaller XML, and taking some number of `<Smt>` elements, and placing number of them into newly formed (smaller) XML message.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Bas>
  <Hdr>
    <Smt>...</Smt>
    <Smt>...</Smt>
    <Smt>...</Smt>
   </Hdr>
</Bas>
```

Currently, I am measuring entire message size `int smtNodesPerMessage = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(xmlStr) / (double)maxSizeBytes);`,followed by 
taking placing `smtNodesPerMessage`  nodes into smaller XML:

```
//doc is original XDocument message
XDocument splitXML = new XDocument(new XElement(doc.Root.Name,                                              
                                   doc.Root.Descendants("Hdr")));
splitXML.Root.Add(batchOfSmt);
```

I quickly found out, is that byte size of smaller XML files is greater than `maxSizeBytes`, since XDocument adds extra characters to each message, increasing byte size.

Comment: Interesting.  Let us know how you go

Comment: Code is probably adding the xml identification to each message : <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: @jdweng, I do, `splitXML.Declaration = doc.Declaration;` but is not in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic algorithm is:

- Get size of document which has empty `Hdr` element. Note that default encoding is UTF-8. So I used `Encoding.Default.GetByteCount` to calcualte size of document and it's element.
- Clone this empty-hdr document for each sub-document
- For eash `Smt` element before adding check whether sub-document size will exceed max value

Code with comments

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var hdr = xdoc.Root.Element("Hdr");
var elements = hdr.Elements().ToList(); 
hdr.RemoveAll(); // we can remove child elements, because they are stored in a list
hdr.Value = "";  // otherwise xdoc will compact empty element to <Hdr/>

// calculating size of sub-document 'template'
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
    doc.Save(writer);
var outerSizeInBytes = Encoding.Default.GetByteCount(sb.ToString());

var maxSizeInBytes = 100;
var subDocumentIndex = 0; // used just for naming sub-document files
var subDocumentSizeBytes = outerSizeInBytes; // initial size of any sub-document
var subDocument = new XDocument(doc); // clone 'template'

foreach (var smt in elements)
{
    var currentElementSizeBytes = Encoding.Default.GetByteCount(smt.ToString());

    if (maxSizeInBytes < subDocumentSizeBytes + currentElementSizeBytes
        && subDocumentSizeBytes != outerSizeInBytes) // case when first element is too big
    {
        subDocument.Save($"doc{++subDocumentIndex}.xml");
        subDocument = new XDocument(doc);
        subDocumentSizeBytes = outerSizeInBytes;
    }

    subDocument.Root.Element("Hdr").Add(smt);
    subDocumentSizeBytes += currentElementSizeBytes;
}

// if current sub-document has elements added, save it too
if (outerSizeInBytes < subDocumentSizeBytes)
    subDocument.Save($"doc{++subDocumentIndex}.xml");
```

---

When source is and max size is 250 bytes, you will get three documents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Bas>
  <Hdr>
    <Smt>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</Smt>
    <Smt>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.</Smt>
    <Smt>It has survived not only five centuries, 
 but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</Smt>
    <Smt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Smt>
  </Hdr>
</Bas>
```

doc1 (223 bytes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bas>
  <Hdr>
    <Smt>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</Smt>
    <Smt>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.</Smt>
  </Hdr>
</Bas>
```

doc2 (259 bytes, single element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bas>
  <Hdr>
    <Smt>It has survived not only five centuries, 
 but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</Smt>
  </Hdr>
</Bas>
```

doc3 (128 bytes, last one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bas>
  <Hdr>
    <Smt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Smt>
  </Hdr>
</Bas>
```

Comment: If you use ascii.GetBytesCount - it is better to declare xml encoding as ascii too (in xml declaration).

Comment: @Evk agree, I just copied bytes calculation method from question. Actually I believe Unicode should be used there

Comment: Yes I think UTF-8 should be used (default for xml if no other encoding specified).